# python install package as sub-package of another package

Tags: python, package, installation

I am developing a program ("homie") in python 2.7 with eclipse / pydev that contains several interfaces to external API providers. Those inherit a genric Interface-Class located inside the `__init__.py` inside `homie.interfaces`

All those interfaces now should be contained in sub-packages of `homie.interfaces`, such like `homie.interfaces.foo` and `homie.interfaces.bar`.
Following the divide-and-conquer concept I created new projects for each interface implementation, containing the respective packages, such like `foo`, respectively `bar`.

The problem is now, that my `setup.py` script does of course not find the package `myprogram.interfaces.foo` during setup. 
Example: The `worknet` interface

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='Worknet-DBs Interface',
    version='0.1-indev',
    author='Richard Neumann',
    author_email='mail@richard-neumann.de',
    packages=['homie.interfaces.worknet'],
    data_files=[],
    license=open('LICENSE.txt').read(),
    description='Interface implementation for the Worknet APIs',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
)
```

Will produce:

```
[neumannr@neumann-homeinfo worknet.tmp]$ python ./setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'homie/interfaces/worknet' does not exist
[neumannr@neumann-homeinfo worknet.tmp]$
```

If I specify just `worknet` instead of `homie.interfaces.worknet` it will of course install into the userbase instad of `homie.interfaces`.
How can I tell the script to install the `worknet` package into `homie.interfaces`, so its path is `homie.interfaces.worknet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Point to your package directory by `package_dir`

`package_dir` parameter can provide information about where to find packages.

### Pointing to existing `worknet` directory

Assuming, `worknet` directory is directly in your project root, you shall dd parameter `package_dir` into your `setup` call

```
package_dir = {'homie.interfaces': ''}
```

### Moving package into subdirectory `homie/interfaces`

Another option is, you reorganize your code directories. E.g .you creat a path `homie/interfaces/` and into it you move the existing `worknet` subdirectory.

In such a case, you would add

```
package_dir = {'homie.interfaces': 'homie/interfaces'}
```